# Setting state with setState doesn't change values

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-state

I am calling fetchProducts in a loop (array.map) from a child component, but don't want have to call it when it's already been done before. Just for testing, I have added "i" which I update after the first call, but this.state.i === 0 is always true, so I keep fetching the same data.

```
fetchProducts = async (id) => {
    if(this.state.i === 0) {
        let url = "http://localhost/mysite/wp-json/mysite/product/" + id

        await fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                ...this.state,
                products: this.state.products.concat([result]),
                i: 1
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Or is there a better way to cache it? The idea is to check for a product ID in this.state.products, instead of "i".

Answer (score 0):

I have two observations.

Firstly, you are setting the state once a promise is resolved.

Secondly, you are calling the fetchProducts through map, which is synchronous.

So, what's happening is, your fetchProducts is keeps on getting called synchronously. That means it doesn't wait for your previous promise to resolve. But you are setting your state after the promise resolved. Hence, it is not guaranteed that when your consecutive fetchProducts are called you would have set the state in the previous function calls.